# checking XSSFCell cellType is Date or not in Java Spring

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to get data from an Excel file into my Spring(Java) web app. I am developing the system which should be suitable for both .xls and .xlsx Excel files. And I want to check whether the cellType of any cell is date, numeric, string, blank etc.
for .xls file, mycode is like that:

```
while (cells.hasNext()) {
                            HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();


                            if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC == cell.getCellType()) { 
                                if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) { 
                                    array.add(df.format(cell.getDateCellValue())); 
                                } else {
                                    int i = (int) cell.getNumericCellValue(); 
                                    array.add(String.valueOf(i)); 
                                }

                            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType()) {
                                array.add((cell.getStringCellValue()).trim());

                            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN == cell.getCellType()) {
                                array.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " ");

                            } else if (HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK == cell.getCellType()) { 
                                array.add(" ");

                            }

                        }
```

Everythin is ok for .xls file.  In .xls file

> if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell))

this code is checking whether the HSSFCell is date or not. And I want to do the same checking with .xlsx file. But I couldn't find any such method. Is there any such method for XSSFCell? I couldn't find
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

For XSSF, you can use DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell) provided by the POI library, that would return boolean. [POI DateUtil](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#isCellDateFormatted(org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell))

Comment: It is exactly what I am searching. It works great, Thank you Rahul.